# How to find the original function from a definite integral.

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I have that $\int_{0}^{x} f(x) \,dx = 2x,$ and I would like to find $f(x)$.

I am not even sure how to begin.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you seen the Fundamental theorem of Calculus?

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, but I do not see the link.

Comment: what happens, if you differentiate $\int_0^x f(t) \mathrm d t$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: @user251257 I am not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) then $f$ defined by
\begin{align}
\int_{ax}^{bx} f(t) \, dt = c \, x,
\end{align}
where $a, b, c$ are constants, can be found in the following way:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{ax}^{bx} f(t) \, dt &= \frac{d}{dx} \, (c \, x) = c \\
\int_{ax}^{bx} \frac{d}{dx}(f(t)) \, dt + f(bx) \, \frac{d(bx)}{dx} - f(ax) \, \frac{d(ax)}{dx} &= c \\
b \, f(bx) - a \, f(ax) &= c \tag{1}
\end{align}
One form of $f(t)$ of (1) is given by
\begin{align}
f(t) = \frac{c}{b-a}.
\end{align}
For the case of $a=0, b=1, c=2$ this leads to $f(t) = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the derivative of $\int_0^x g(t)dt$ is $g(x)$ whenever $g$ is continuous (See [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) as mentioned by David). To get $g(\tilde x)$ you can calculate $\frac{d}{dx}\left.\int_0^x g(t)dt\right|_{x=\tilde x}$ ...

Comment: What does 'continuous' mean?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

find f(x) for  $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) \,dx = 2\ a$

By inspection f(x) = 2 is one solution.

$ Anyone $ among an infinite set of functions that removes area from first half and deposits on the second half satisfies it. It is up to your imagination or familiarity with function forms to suggest a solution.

One simple example where center point $(x,1)$ is chosen constant:

$$ f(x) = 2 + A \, \sin \frac {\pi \, x}{\lambda} $$ where $ A, \lambda $ are constants. $\lambda$ is wave length of sine-wave. Other functions which are "odd" with respect to this point are possible.

If you choose segments in ratio 1:3 , area average height should be 3:1, and so on.